# Nested virtualization - VirtualBox on Linux in Hyper-V

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v

Say one tries to use Windows 10 Pro or Windows Server 2016 Standard with Hyper-V, to host a Linux distribution such as CentOS, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, or Ubuntu, and run VirtualBox on that Linux guest. Is that possible?

Comment: Hyper-V does indeed supports nested virtualization.  What part of the process are you stuck on exactly?  You should edit your question to refine your question.

Comment: Hyper-V only supports nested virtualization for specific OSes, AFIIK, its still only Windows 10/2016 and higher that work.  If you run Linux as a VM, you won't get any of the hardware virtualization features passed through from the CPU and you'll only be able to run a 32bit OS in VirtualBox.